# Is it possible to add an affiliation to the DESCRIPTION-file of an R-package?

Tags: r, package, publishing

I wonder if it is possible to add an affiliation (company/institute/university) to the DESCRIPTION-file of an R-package?

I found [this (quasi) idendical question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-January/300130.html). The question is five years old now and I wonder if in the meanwhile there is a better answer than "Write a [package name].Rd topic, and put the information in there. It won't show up on the title page of the reference manual, but it will be the first topic." If I look at the [Section 1.1.1. of the "Writing R Extensions"-document](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) I find no hint about an affilition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `comment` parameter of `person` in `Authors@R`. Now the questions what the purpose of giving that affiliation is, how it could impact the license, and what CRAN's position on this is are all important follow-up questions that I can't answer.

Comment: To make it fool prove: in my `Authors@R` the entries now look like `person("Jon", "Doe", role = "aut", comment = "XY affiliation")`